# Scheduling sequential executions in Tkinter with delays

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, delay

I am trying to execute functions which alter my tkinter UI's appearance sequentially, but with a delay during which the user can view the state after the first change, but before the second.

I quickly learned not to use `time.sleep(1000)` to insert a 1 second delay, as it caused the UI to stall (and crash, on my machine. Though other answers stated it should not have crashed).

I've instead tried using `.after(1000)`;

```
def callback():
    self.colorFrame.configure(background="red")
    self.after(1000)
    self.colorFrame.configure(background="black")

self = tk.Tk()

self.colorFrame = tk.Frame(self, width=500, height=500)
self.colorFrame.pack()
self.parentFrame = tk.Frame(self)
self.parentFrame.pack()
self.button = tk.Button(self.parentFrame, text="Trigger Changes", command=callback)
self.button.pack()

tk.mainloop()
```

On my machine, at least, running that snippet creates a window with a button which when pressed turns the frame above it black 1 second later. I never see any red background. Am I misusing the function? Or is this the wrong approach?

Comment: `.after()` with one parameter is the moral equivalent of `time.sleep()` - it simply locks up the GUI for the duration.  You need to use the 2+ parameter version, which schedules a function for execution in the future.

Comment: If that were true, I would expect the UI element to turn red, lock up for a second, and then turn black. Is that wrong?

Comment: Moreover, doing it the way you suggest (which absolutely does work, but I'm still curious as to why the method I used above doesn't) would mean that any time I want to do a large series of instructions, I need one additional function for every single delay I want to insert, and they all need to be chained rather than allowed to execute and return to the previous scope. That seems significantly more annoying to maintain.

Comment: Tkinter widget state changes (such as via `.configure()`) have no immediate visual effect - they are updated in bulk via the mainloop, but that can't happen if your code is blocked in a long-running call rather than returning.  Read up on the concept of *state machines* - you don't actually need a separate function per step, you can single function that reschedules itself, and keeps track of what it needs to do next.

Comment: Okay. Thank you. If you want to submit that as an answer I would accept it. Otherwise I will update my example code to use a state machine approach and post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

As jasonharper suggested, a state machine is a better way of achieving this result without chaining individual function calls together. For the case of color cycling I came up with this code:

```py
import tkinter as tk

def callback():
    colorCycleStateMap = {
        "red": "orange",
        "orange": "yellow",
        "yellow": "green",
        "green": "violet",
        "violet": "indigo",
        "indigo": "blue",
        "blue": "black",
        "black": "break"
    }
    currentColor = self.colorFrame["background"]
    if colorCycleStateMap[currentColor] == "break":
        return
    
  self.colorFrame.configure(background=colorCycleStateMap[currentColor])
    self.after(1000, callback)

self = tk.Tk()

self.colorFrame = tk.Frame(self, width=500, height=500, background="red")
self.colorFrame.pack()
self.parentFrame = tk.Frame(self)
self.parentFrame.pack()
self.button = tk.Button(self.parentFrame, text="Trigger Changes", command=callback)
self.button.pack()

tk.mainloop()
```